# display current information from array when clicking on a specific element

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, arraylist

I have an array of objects. When you click on the card, a popup with information is displayed. How can I display the current information that corresponds to the card that I clicked. I display information for all animals, but how to display information for a specific card

```
const pets = [
    {
      "name": "Jennifer",
      "img": "../../assets/images/pets-jennifer.png",
      "type": "/",
    },
    {
      "name": "Sophia",
      "img": "../../assets/images/pets-sophia.png",
      "type": "/",
    },
    {
      "name": "Woody",
      "img": "../../assets/images/pets-woody.png",
      "type": "..",
    }
]
document.querySelectorAll('.pet_card').forEach(card => card.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modal.classList.add('show-modal')
})) 
document.querySelector('.modal').innerHTML = `
    ${pets.map(petTemplate).join('')}
`;
function petTemplate(pet) {
    return `
        <div class="modal_wrap">
            <div class="modal_img">
                <img src="${pet.img}">
            </div>
            <div class="modal_content">
                <h3>${pet.name}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    `;
}
<div class="main_pets_wrap">
  <div class="pet_card">
    <h5>Woody</h5>
    <button class="pet_card_btn">Learn more</button>
  </div>
  <div class="pet_card">
    <h5>Jennifer</h5>
    <button class="pet_card_btn">Learn more</button>
  </div>
  .....
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```html
<!-- Add this div -->
<div class="modal"></div>
```

```
// Create an array out of node list by using the spread operator
[...document.querySelectorAll('.pet_card')].forEach(card =>
    card.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
       let pet = findSelectedPet(event.target);
       let modal = petTemplate(pet);
       document.querySelector(".modal").innerHTML = modal;
}));

// This is how you should find the pet information.
function findSelectedPet(btn) {
  let name = btn.querySelector("h5").innerText;
  return pets.find(pet => pet.name == name);
}

// I didn't touch this function.
function petTemplate(pet) {
    return `
        <div class="modal_wrap">
            <div class="modal_img">
                <img src="${pet.img}">
            </div>
            <div class="modal_content">
                <h3>${pet.name}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    `;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. Because when you click on a card, the target can be a picture, it cannot find h5. There is a error Cannot read property 'innerText' of null at let name = btn.parentElement.querySelector('h5').innerText;

Comment: and when we click on other card, the the show name and information only for first card

Comment: It worked on CodePen. Make sure you check the changes carefully. https://codepen.io/bulentAkgul/pen/eYzBLWM

Comment: but if i want to click on all div (pet_card), how can i find h5 inside the div?

Comment: it show the error - Cannot read property 'innerText' of null

Comment: I gave you a working CodePen link. if the code gives an error, there must be a mistake you made when you get it.

Comment: No, it doesn't make errors. I don't want to spend more time just because you refuse to read 2 lines of code carefully.

Comment: I find a mistake why it doesn't work. When i changed eventTarget to eventcurrentTarget, it worked. Whith evenTarget it doesn't work. So thank you very much and sorry for the importunity